# Is there a console command that'll terminate a message?

Tags: fallout-3

I have a couple of mods which are used to give me companions, one of which adds a "Friend" option to the dialog of most characters and allows me to recruit them. For the most part this fine but on occasion it sometimes leads me into a situation where "Friend" is the only option and no terminating dialog choice. In these situations I can generally just avoid the character.

In the Anchorage DLC however I have came across this problem with Specialist Olin where no matter the choices I get to this dead end. I don't really want to disable the mods I have so I am wondering, is there a console command I can execute to terminate the message box?

Comment: ~closeallmenus [Quick exit for conversations](https://forums.nexusmods.com/index.php?/topic/203015-quick-exit-for-conversations/). Also try CoC and save/load.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use the console command `CAM` to close out of dialog menus. In context, the command CAM means "CloseAllMenus".

For additional reference you can view all console commands available in Fallout 3 [by clicking this link](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Gamebryo_console_commands_(all))